# the year of my date column is not displaying

Tags: python, list, datetime

The date column in my csv file has just month and day '02-March' but after filtering the column in excel It shows that the year of each entry is available.

Reading this file using the csv module in python, the dates are appearing the same way

```
acw_user_data = "data.csv"

with open(acw_user_data, 'r') as csvfile:
    data = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter = ',')
    line_count = 0
    for row in data:
        if line_count == 0:
            print("FIELD_NAME_ARE: %s" % (row))
            line_count += 1
        else:
            print("THE_ROW_VALUES_ARE: %s" % (row))
            line_count += 1
```

`

THE_ROW_VALUES_ARE: ['00 Wheeler wells', 'Chapmanton', 'L2 7BT', '46', '13.72', 'Begum-Williams', '12-Aug', '26-Nov', '4.52944E+15', '583', '1', 'Jonathan', 'GB37UMCO54540228728019', 'Thomas', 'married or civil partner', '0', 'FALSE', '54016', 'Male', 'Nissan', 'ATS', '1996', 'Coupe'
`

I want to change the data type of the dates to date time.

```
expiry_date = [d.get("Credit Card Expiry Date") for d in Credit_Card_info]

for item in expiry_date:
    try:
        item = item.replace("/", "-")
        expiry_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(item,'%d-%b').date()
        print(expiry_date)
    except ValueError:
        print("ValueError in: ")
        print(item)
```

`1900-11-27 1900-11-26 1900-07-27 1900-04-18 1900-11-27 1900-05-15 1900-03-29 1900-04-27 1900-08-20 1900-10-13 1900-03-29`

Instead of the year of each elements, it replaces it by 1900

Comment: See [time.strptime too strict? should it assume current year](https://bugs.python.org/issue2227).

Comment: Since we have leap years, you'll have to default to *some* year so that you don't end up with undefined behavior (Feb 29). Besides, 1900 is ***not*** a leap year as it's divisible by 100 but not 400.